# Issue with Rails migrations Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a strange problem with rails migrations.
My db/migrate folder contains migration files and all worked fine.
But a few moment ago, I created a new file using `rails g migration MigrationName`, it generated a new file. then when i had runned `rake db:migrate` it rollbacks all and my schema version became 0.
Now when i run `rake db:migrate` it does nothing whereas db/migrate contains all my migrations.
i tried `rake db:reset db:drop db:create db:migrate` but no migrations was performed. However it says "migrations are pending run rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development" what i've done in vain.

I'm confused. Is anyone ever had this problem?

i've just tried `RAILS_ENV=development rake db:migrate --trace` and it returns:

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:dump
```

Running:

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

gives me:

```
database: database_development 
Status Migration ID Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
up 000 ********** NO FILE ********** 
down 20150613120151 Devise create users 
down 20150613120734 Devise create admins 
down 20150614114949 Create gender 
down 20150614115642 Create events 
down 20150614142610 Create multi events
```

I tried so many things:
- i dropped my database, restarted postgresql and run again `rake db:setup db:migrate`. `rake db:migrate:status` tells me that migrations are pending but it wont migrate.
it makes me crazy...

EDIT
I manually updated schema_migrations in database adding the timestamps
schema:load worked, but when i run rake db:migrate to check if its all good, it rolledback..

EDIT
if i manually fill schema_migrations version in database with timestamps, when i do `rake db:schema:status` they are all to up and my new migration to down, but if i do `rake db:migrate` it tries to revert as if i wanted to run `rake db:rollback`

Comment: hello, thanks for helping. I don't know what is this 000 migration. I don't understand too. I tried to migrate with production environment on my local machine it works.

Comment: i'll try this. But this 000 migration comes everytime i run rake db:create

Comment: Ok it seems normal that Rails generates this `000` file then you run `db:create`.

Answer (score 2):

So i fixed my issue.
In fact, i'm using dotenv to manage environment vars for development, and in my .env file i defined a var called VERSION to describe the API version...
That is the bug !
When i removed it, rake was able to migrate as expected.

Comment: I had this same problem! Thanks for saving me some time.

Comment: I had the same issue and fixed by unset VERSION the same as you. How ever, It's not a bug. The db:migrate use var VERSION to migrate the specific version. So in our case, it intends to run the specific version set in the ENV variable.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will work for, but can you please try the following things,

First, drop tables

```
rake db:drop
```

Second, Delete/Remove `db/schema.rb` file

Third, create database

```
rake db:create
```

Fourth, run migration again

```
rake db:migrate
```

Please let me know if this help you a bit, good luck :)